# Why is JavaScript click not working in Rselenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a web page with a JavaScript drop down menu in R. I can follow the directions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109267/rselenium-and-javascript), but nothing happens and no errors are shown. Instead, it gives an empty list:

```
dropdown <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "s2id_autogen4_search")
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','select2-input select2-focused');", list(dropdown))
> list()
```

Also, nothing happens (and no console output) with `dropdown$clickElement()`.

This is somewhat related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923316/rselenium-select-dropdown-combobox-value-from-javascript-list?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I need to click first to activate the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mask over it, so I needed to find the mask, click on that, then supply arguments to the dropdown itself:

```
dropdown <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "s2id_autogen4_search")
mask <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='select2-drop-mask']") 
mask$clickElement()
dropdown$sendKeysToElement(list("l"))
```